# Is there a way to change data using SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, triplestore

I want to change the data in my triple store using SPARQL. Is DELETE and INSERT the only way?

Comment: yes, that is the only way - which way else you need? Or which kind of change operation? Note, the smallest unit in RDF is basically a triple, thus, something like renaming a node needs to remove/insert all triples involving the node at any position - indeed, a triple store might provide convenience on top of SPARQL

Comment: I am using the triple store using Jena's SDB. I'd like to use SPARQL update to change the data stored here.

Comment: So you are using a relational database as backend? May I ask why? Why not using a more native triple store like TDB2 then? Anyway, the only SPARQL way to change data is to is `DELETE {} INSERT {} WHERE {}`

Comment: Yes I'm using a relational database as backend. There is no reason, but I have examples and data for making triple storage using sdb, but I don't have examples and data using TDB.
As a final question, can I use SPARQL update in SDB?

Comment: The interface to query and update TDB is the same as SDB. The only difference is the dataset creation step.