# How to use SPARQL update in Jena SDB

Tags: sparql, jena, triplestore

I saved the following RDF/XML documents in a triple store(Jena SDB)

```
<rdf:RDF 
xmlns:ex="http://www.example#" 
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xml:base="http://www.test#">

<ex:cat rdf:ID="_101">
   <ex:name>Milk</ex:name>
</ex:cat>
<ex:dog rdf:ID="_2001">
   <ex:name>Lub</ex:name>
</ex:dog>
</rdf:RDF>
```

To

```
ex:_101 rdf:type ex:cat
ex:_101 ex:name "Milk"
ex:_201 rdf:type ex:dog
ex:_201 ex:name "Lub"
```

Then I want to change ex:name to ex:aliasname using SPARQL update
Query :

```
DELETE { ?s ex:name ?o }
INSERT { ?s ex:aliasname ?o }
WHERE { ?s ex:name ?o }
```

Wish

```
ex:_101 rdf:type ex:cat
ex:_101 ex:aliasname "Milk"
ex:_201 rdf:type ex:dog
ex:_201 ex:aliasname "Lub"
```

But I don't know how to apply this.
I'm referring to the following site.
https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/
https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/update.html
I'd appreciate any advice or link you give me
Thank you in advance

Comment: maybe I repeat myself, but what can't you load the RDF/XML file to a TDB2 triple store?

Comment: other than that, you do you use the SDB database? Via Fuseki? via plain Java code with JENA API? With API it's nothing more than a `Dataset`, querying works like here: https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/jena-3.17.0/jena-sdb/src-examples/sdb/examples/Ex2.java - running a SPARQL Update command on the dataset could work then as well

Comment: Is it right to operate TDB on the web using Fuseki? My major is not a computer scientist, so I don't know anything about computers. Another person looked at one example and thus used SDB. I'm using Java code with JENA API from download here : https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.apache.jena/jena-sdb?p=2

Comment: I'm sorry, but in the link you gave me, it doesn't look like a code that changes the data of the triple store through SPARQL update. Did I get it wrong?

Comment: Ex2 contains the line:  `Dataset ds = DatasetStore.create(store) ;` - replace the query example with an update. The update code is the same for any Jena storage choice as noted on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74871340

Comment: "Is it right to operate TDB on the web using Fuseki?"- -- yes, it it the preferred choice. And use current Jena v4.6.1

Comment: @user20297975 I'd definitely say, if you already have RDF data, the best way would be to use TDB(2) in combination with Fuseki